# Conversion failed error when using SELECT TOP but no error when selecting all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion, sql-server-2017

SSMS - SQL 2017
I am selecting records from view - 3 scenarios and query fails in one with error.

```
SELECT top 94 *
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[test1]
```

Result:(94 rows affected)

```
SELECT top 95 *
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[test1]
```

Result:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```
SELECT *
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[test1]
```

Result : (24934 rows affected)

This puzzles me. How come SELECT gives error in 2nd scenario and it doesn't in 3rd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are scenarios where this can occur.  Generally, this type of conversion error is in a `select` expression or `where` expression that has the type incompatibility.

What your results are saying is that:

- There are bad rows in the data.
- These are being filtered out by the view.
- The view can change query plans, so sometimes the bad rows are sometimes evaluated and sometimes not.

My best guess is that you are seeing a change in query plan.  When you select 95 rows, the query plan is processing the data and finding the error.  The row with the error would be filtered out later, but the error has already occurred.

When you select all the rows, the query plan changes and the error no longer occurs because the filtering takes place before the conversion error.

For example, consider this query:

```
select . . .
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.x = t2.x
where t1.col1 = 5 and
      cast(t2.col2 as date) = cast(getdate() as date);  -- this generates the error
```

This can be evaluated in two ways.  With `t1` as the driving table, the filter on "5" is executed for all rows.  But only matching rows in `t2` are ever filtered.  So, no error occurs.

Alternatively, `t2` could be filtered and the filter is applied to all rows.  Error!  We never get further to learn that the error rows would have been filtered out.

The choice of execution plans could be based on the number of rows being returned.  Or, the costs might be exactly the same and SQL Server arbitrarily chooses one of them.

Comment: Can you clarify if I understand this answer correctly: Are you suggesting that the view might be something like: `select * from my_table where int_col>10 and convert(date, text_col) > getdate()`, and in the OP's failed query, the query plan is evaluating the `text_col` filter first (where there is bad data), but in the successful query it is evaluating `int_col` first, which filters out the rows with bad "date" data before they get evaluated?

Comment: @RToyo . . . Something to that effect.  I would expect the situation to be a bit more subtle, involving perhaps the choice of indexes for a `join`.  That can in turn determine which filtering is happening when the data is read in.

Comment: Thank you for responding. That makes sense, especially with your update to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, this make sense. The view is build over number other views and I even found where the error can occur in one of underlying views.